# How do they capture Rocky Mountain Goats in order to relocate them?

Tags: conservation, rocky-mountain-goats

In Grand Teton National Park they have Rocky Mountain Goats and Bighorn Sheep and because they are worried that the goats will spread diseases to the sheep, they want to mountain goats gone from the Teton Range.

How do they capture the goats alive so they can relocate them somewhere else?

Answer (score 3):

A recent-ish article in the [Seattle Times](https://projects.seattletimes.com/2018/moving-mountain-goats/) on moving goats out of Olympic National Park covers the situation pretty well.

From a helicopter, the goat is either (1) darted, or (2) directly caught in a net. The animal is then made safe for transport, and helicoptered out to a staging area. From there, they are trucked to a final destination.